# Is there a uuid validator annotation?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I can't find a `@UUID` (or similar) annotation for validating input parameters in a java web app.

I've looked so far in

1. javax.validation.constraints
2. org.hibernate.validator.constraints

Comment: If you want to make validation on **@RestController** endpoint then I think easier is to just expect the **java.util.UUID** type. If there will be not possible to map the value from HTTP request to valid UUID then spring just refuse the request  :)

Comment: At least now, `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.UUID` is in place and we're using it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the time of the question there wasn't one but in the meantime it has been added starting with org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/UUID.html

Answer (score 46):

yes, build it by yourself

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$")
public @interface UUID {
    String message() default "{invalid.uuid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaiwo99 I was hoping validating uuids is common enough so that it is already included in libraries and I don't need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: In case of constraint violation this returns the error message of the @Pattern annotation, not the custom `message()`. To return the custom error message set from outside, you can add `javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation` metaannotation.

Comment: @Jaiwo99 your interface not work for me. it not throw me custom message. neither default message.

Comment: This regex will invalidate all upper case or if a single upper case char is present in the UUID.

Comment: @dazito Hi, you are right, but this is not the ultimate solution for all possible UUID validation, feel free to change it so that it suits your requirement.

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out in case someone does a copy paste and then is wondering why it is failing (in case it fails) :)

Comment: @dazito This can easily be fixed by passing the `Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to `@Pattern`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 You cannot apply the '@Pattern' annotation to something (java.util.UUID) that is not a CharSequence.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868539/validate-uuid-restful-service

Comment: @ankit the proper answer for UUID validation can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868539/validate-uuid-restful-service/

Answer (score 23):

**[Updated]**

The solution from @Jaiwo99 will not display the specified message, it will instead display the error message from `@Pattern`. To fix this issue, just add `@ReportAsSingleViolation` annotation to @Jaiwo's solution. (@LudovicRonsin pointed this out in a comment to this answer, and @helospark in a comment to @Jaiwo99's answer.)

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$")
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface UUID {
    String message() default "{invalid.uuid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**[Old Answer]**

The solution from Jaiwo99 works, but I was unable to set a custom message from the outside (it is overriden by the message from `@Pattern`). If you need that, I propose that you simply use something like this:

```
@Pattern(regexp = SomeUtilClass.UUID_PATTERN, message = "TokenFormatError")
private String token;
```

You can put the pattern in some static final field to avoid duplication:

```
public static SomeUtilClass {
    public static final String UUID_PATTERN = "^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$";
}
```

Comment: There are at least 3 ways of defining your own message in a composed constraint (like in @Jaiwo99 answer)
* Set the `@Pattern` message field with a static default message.
* Use `@javax.validation.OverridesAttribute` to override `@Pattern` default message and give the ability to contextualise with constraint usage.
* `@javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation` to return only the message set by your annotation.
In this particular case, I would use `@ReportAsSingleViolation`
See https://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition

Answer (score 3):

Same as @Jaiwo99's answer , but as @mrzli pointed out, the pattern's message overrides any custom messages. Using message in the @Pattern will fix that if you want custom messages.

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$", message = "Not a valid UUID")
public @interface UUID {
    String message() default "{invalid.uuid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```