# Validate UUID Restful service

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a RESTful service which receives `POST` request with `UUID` values and writes them in DB. So the problem is to validate if `UUID` is valid or not. For this purpose I implemented custom annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp = "[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[34][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}")
public @interface validUuid {

    String message() default "{invalid.uuid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work, even if I pass valid `UUID` I constantly get an exception:

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator 
>     could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' 
>     validating type 'java.util.UUID'

Are there any options to validate `UUID` properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot apply the [`@Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation to something ([`java.util.UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)) that is not a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). From the [`@Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation documentation (emphesizes mine):

> Accepts **CharSequence**. null elements are considered valid.

Moreover, as far as I see you try to extend the behavior of the validation annotation handler by passing it to the new annotation definition.

If you wish to perform more complex validation, simply create your annotation *without* another validation annotations - their combining doesn't work like this. There must be *something* to recognize annotations and validate them.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UuidValidator.class)
public @interface ValidUuid {

    String message() default "{invalid.uuid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Now, create a validator which implements [`ConstraintValidator<ValidUuid, UUID>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) and override the methods performing the validation itself.

```
public class UuidValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidUuid, UUID> {
    private final String regex = "....." // the regex

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidUuid validUuid) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UUID uuid, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return uuid.toString().matches(this.regex);
    }
}
```

And apply the annotation:

```
@ValidUuid
private UUID uuId;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe there is a problem, I don't use String I use UUID type:

  `@validUuid (message = "Please provide valid UUID")`

  `private UUID uuid;`

Comment: I have edited my answer. You cannot use `@Pattern` to `java.util.UUID`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis it is not working unless you add `@Constraint(validatedBy = UuidValidator.class)` to the ValidUuid Interface

Comment: @Mojtaba: That's true, I wonder how I could had missed it. Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Not necessarily required to create a custom validator. You can compose the constraints as the question's example code exhibits. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/7.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-composition

Comment: @juliaaano: Since when is this feature available? I havent seen it before.

Comment: Not sure, but I found on Hibernate's documentation as early as version 4.x. There is this other answer from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320870/is-there-a-uuid-validator-annotation

Comment: Ah right, I am sorry, I scrolled to ValueExtractor and I though it is somehow associated with the valudations somehow after skimming throught the articles.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UUID.fromString(...)`; and catch `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: uuid.fromstring() will not work in jdk version 8
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8159339 ,