# How to make custom annotation throw an error instead of default message

Tags: java, java-annotations

I am working on an api that allows the user to fetch data by id, where the id's data type is a UUID. I would like to use an annotation in the controller method to check whether the user passed a valid UUID, but @Valid doesn't work on UUID's, so I want to write my own. Here is how I want to use my custom annotation in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getById(@PathVariable @ValidUUID String id) {
        MyObject payload = service.getById(id);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(payload);
    }
```

I have written a global exception handler:

```
import com.testapp.exceptions.InvalidUUIDException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidUUIDException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidUUIDException(InvalidUUIDException ex) {
        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        body.put("message", ex.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

and a custom exception:

```
public class InvalidUUIDException extends RuntimeException {
    public InvalidUUIDException(String id) {
        super(String.format("The UUID provided (%s) is not valid", id));
    }
}
```

My problem is when I try to write the custom annotation, I can't figure out how to make it throw a custom exception. I found several discussions online, including [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320870/is-there-a-uuid-validator-annotation) that talks about creating a custom annotation (the code below is from that question). All of the examples I have found just return a string, and don't allow throwing a custom exception (in my case InvalidUUIDException). Any thoughts on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$")
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface UUID {
    String message() default "{invalid.uuid}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't using `java.util.UUID` as the parameter type? (To your main question, it is not customary for constraints to throw exceptions; their validators report errors using an error API, and any exception happens at a higher level.)

Comment: You make a good point. I was defining the parameter as String because the user could put any text into the url. Before I started trying to implement a custom validator, I had logic in the controller that used regex to check if the provided id was valid, then converted the string to a UUID. Now that I am using the validator, I could change the type to UUID.

Comment: Any solution to the original question, how to throw exception from the custom annotation ?